# how to write or set parameter value from fulfillment in dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Basically I need to be able to write a result from fullfillment to a previously defined dialogflow parameter.

I can receive the values of the variables from dialogflow to fullfillment, but when I write back I do not get the expected result. An example of the function is the following:

```
function Validate(agent){
    let P1 = agent.parameters.rut1.Rut; //<<----received OK
    let P2 = agent.parameters.rut1.dv;  //<<----received OK
    let P3;

    P3 = some_function(P1,P2); //<<----------For example

    agent.parameters.next_state = P3; //<<---here the result is not written to the parameter.
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1pao.png)

Comment: It isn't clear how you're verifying that it isn't set to the parameter, or what you're trying to do with it if it was. Generally parameters from the agent are only valid in the webhook. What are you trying to do with it once it is set?

Comment: If you want to use data across fulfillments, you need to [Save data within conversations](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/save-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameters exists within the output contexts in Fulfillment response (V2).
You need to specify the parameter you want to add / update in your respective output context while sending response back from your web hook

```
                response.send(JSON.stringify({
                "fulfillmentText": "Hello, welcome to bot service. I need you to sign in first, your Userid?",
                "outputContexts": [
                    {
                        "name": request.body.session + "/contexts/usercontext",
                        "lifespanCount": 5,
                        "parameters": {
                            "token": result.access_token
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }));
```

You can then have this parameter value in your subsequent 5 invoked intents.